# Ball Bouncing Lab in C

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am trying to make my C code work with an MSP-EXP432P4111 Microcontroller and its BoosterPack so that a ball can bounce around on the screen, bouncing off the walls and corners of the screen, which is 128 x 128 pixels. Currently, the ball will fly into the corner but it won't bounce back, and I will lose the ball. How do I fix this so it keeps bouncing?

```
#include <ti/devices/msp432p4xx/driverlib/driverlib.h>
#include <ti/grlib/grlib.h>
#include "LcdDriver/Crystalfontz128x128_ST7735.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//*****************************************************************************
Graphics_Context g_sContext;
volatile uint32_t flag; //global flag
volatile uint32_t window_height;
volatile uint32_t window_width;
volatile int32_t x; // x position
volatile int32_t y; // y position
volatile int32_t vx; // x velocity
volatile int32_t vy; // y velocity
const int32_t radius = 3;
volatile uint32_t hits; // # of wall hits
volatile uint32_t hitCounter; //used to reset velocity
int32_t oldx;  // Variable to store the previous x position
int32_t oldy;  // Variable to store the previous y position
volatile bool xDirectionPositive;  // Flag indicating the direction of x movement
volatile bool yDirectionPositive;  // Flag indicating the direction of y movement
volatile uint32_t flag;  // Flag variable

void SysTick_Handler(void){
   flag = 1;
}

//*****************************************************************************
void LCD_init(){
//add LCD related codes in here
    Crystalfontz128x128_Init(); //initializes display
    Crystalfontz128x128_SetOrientation(LCD_ORIENTATION_UP); //set default screen orientation
    Graphics_initContext(&g_sContext, &g_sCrystalfontz128x128, &g_sCrystalfontz128x128_funcs);
    Graphics_setForegroundColor(&g_sContext, GRAPHICS_COLOR_RED);
    Graphics_setBackgroundColor(&g_sContext, GRAPHICS_COLOR_WHITE);
    GrContextFontSet(&g_sContext, &g_sFontFixed6x8);
    Graphics_clearDisplay(&g_sContext);
}

//*****************************************************************************
void erase(int32_t x, int32_t y, int32_t radius){
// draw over old with background color to erase it
    Graphics_setForegroundColor(&g_sContext, GRAPHICS_COLOR_WHITE);
    Graphics_drawCircle(&g_sContext, x, y , radius);
    //restore foreground color setting
    Graphics_setForegroundColor(&g_sContext, GRAPHICS_COLOR_RED);
}

//*****************************************************************************
void draw(int32_t x, int32_t y, int32_t radius){
// draw circle with default foreground color
    Graphics_drawCircle(&g_sContext , x, y , radius);
}

//*****************************************************************************

 int main(void) {
     SysTick_enableModule();
     x = 64;
     y = 64;
     vx = 1;
     vy = -1;
     hits = 0;
     hitCounter = 0;
     window_height = 127;
     window_width = 127;
     oldx = x;
     oldy = y;
     xDirectionPositive = true;
     yDirectionPositive = true;

     WDT_A_holdTimer();

     LCD_init();
     SysTick_setPeriod(30000);
     SysTick_enableInterrupt();

     // ... (existing code)

     while (1)
     {
         if (flag == 1)
         {
             erase(oldx, oldy, radius); // Erase the old circle at its previous position

             // Update ball position
             oldx = x;  // Save the current x as the old x
             oldy = y;  // Save the current y as the old y

             // Check if the ball is hitting the left or right wall
             if ((x + radius >= window_width && xDirectionPositive) || (x - radius <= 0 && !xDirectionPositive))
             {
                 xDirectionPositive = !xDirectionPositive;  // Toggle the x-direction flag
                 vx = (xDirectionPositive) ? 1 : -1;  // Reset velocity based on x direction flag

                 // Increase the magnitude of the x-velocity up to a maximum of 15
                 if (vx < 0)
                 {
                     vx = (-vx) < 15 ? (-vx) + 1 : 15;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     vx = vx < 15 ? vx + 1 : 15;
                 }

                 hits++; // Increment hits counter when the ball hits the wall
             }

             // Check if the ball is hitting the top or bottom wall
             if ((y + radius >= window_height && yDirectionPositive) || (y - radius <= 0 && !yDirectionPositive))
             {
                 yDirectionPositive = !yDirectionPositive;  // Toggle the y-direction flag
                 vy = (yDirectionPositive) ? 1 : -1;  // Reset velocity based on y direction flag

                 // Increase the magnitude of the y-velocity up to a maximum of 15
                 if (vy < 0)
                 {
                     vy = (-vy) < 15 ? (-vy) + 1 : 15;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     vy = vy < 15 ? vy + 1 : 15;
                 }

                 hits++; // Increment hits counter when the ball hits the wall
             }

             // Check if 50 hits are reached to reset velocities
             if (hits >= 50)
             {
                 hits = 0; // Reset hits counter
                 hitCounter++;

                 // Reset velocities to have magnitude 1 while maintaining the current direction
                 if (hitCounter % 2 == 0)
                 {
                     vx = (xDirectionPositive) ? 1 : -1;  // Reset based on x direction flag
                     vy = (yDirectionPositive) ? 1 : -1;  // Reset based on y direction flag
                 }
             }

             x += vx; // Update x based on velocity
             y += vy; // Update y based on velocity

             draw(x, y, radius); // Draw the new circle at its updated position

             flag = 0;
         }
     }
   }
```

I tried to change the conditions in the ternary operator, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Suggestion: work out the "bouncing" logic based on, perhaps, a VT100 display device. You might get some help from those of us who lack the particular hardware configuration you are using. Once the "rebounding" logic is solved, you could then transfer this to your specific hardware and display device. As it stands, your problem is not **reproducible** by the majority of your readers.

Comment: Also, check the resulting sign on your "bounce-back" velocity (or whatever it is), e.g. `vx = (-vx) < 15 ? (-vx) + 1 : 15;` seems to take a velocity in the negative direction and make it positive while the `else {...}` computation doesn't switch the sign. Good choice on using `driverlib` -- great library and mnemonics are much easier to learn than CMSIS registers and bits.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
if ((x + radius > window_width ) || (x - radius < 0)){...}
if ((y + radius > window_height) || (y - radius < 0)){...}
```

As you can see I modified the main condition. Changed `<=` for `<` because you dont want it to be on the border, you want the ball to bounce, barely touch it.

I also removed `&& xDirectionPositive` part in each condition, it redundant. You just have to toggle wichever is the case.

As far as I can see the only thing that might cause the ball to dont bounce is that you're handling incorrectly the direction (`xDirectionPositive` or `&& yDirectionPositive`).

I would suggest you to first make the ball bounce and then add the velocity increment part.

Comment: Didn't work, I still have the same result